# JSF + Openshift redirect not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I 'm doing a project with JSF 2 OpenShift ( JBoss 7 server as obvious ) and I can not solve a problem by redirecting via Bean. I'm trying everything locally with Glassfish. My problem occurs when I try to access the " access.xhml " page, to monitor users logged I put the following:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{sesion.checkSession()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

In the definition of the method I have the following

```
public void checkSession() throws IOException{
    faceContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)faceContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if(httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("connected")==null)
    {
        faceContext.getExternalContext().redirect(faceContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/index.xhtml"); // For local changes
    }
}
```

Proving what returns

```
faceContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()
```

I note that it is always " " , which indicates to me that the redirect should go to the root. The point is that when I try it directly entering www.my-app.rhcloud.com/access.xhtml always throws 500 error

```
Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl...
at org.sindicatopygp.beans.SessionBean.checkSession(SessionBean.java:43)
```

Any ideas? We thank

Comment: What is the exact, full message title? Is it only, `Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.: java.lang.IllegalStateException`?

Comment: The full exception is so much large, this exception must be the problem (I guess). The others are cascade exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . For some reason index.xhtml not recognize the file, if redirected to the servlet root taking and successfully redirected to file index.xhtml. The solution

```
public void checkSession() throws IOException{
    if(httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("connected")==null)
    {
        try {
            faceContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/index.xhtml"); //For logged users
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                faceContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/"); //For external visitors
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //For other problems...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo Mendoza for president